# Forge.ui.enhanceInput - activated on touchStart? Interferes with scrolling

Tags: trigger.io

I'm using forge.ui.enhanceAllInputs() to get native date pickers on Android

It causes a problem with scrolling however. If you touch and drag on the page to scroll, if your finger starts on the enhanced field the date picker shows immediately. It doesn't give time to scroll.

So in effect you go to scroll the page, but end up with a date picker appearing unintentionally.

It seems like the date picker is being called on touchStart, where as perhaps on touchEnd may give the expected experience.

Comment: Yep, good point - I've created a story for it: we'll fix in an upcoming sprint.

Answer (score 0):

A fix for this went into v1.4.31 of our platform - see http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/release-notes.html

Comment: Thanks James, have just tried it out. It is better, but still does quite work as expected - back to the problem I described of trying to scroll the page: With this update the date picker still appears, it just now appears when you finger leaves the screen. For example: touch and hold on a date picker field, and then drag your finger off (onto the page background) and release - the picker appears. This is different to native field or button behaviour - where the input would not have been activated.

Comment: Cool, glad that's working better for you. I don't quite follow the second issue - how are you starting to scroll with your finger on top of a date input, and ending with your finger off the input? Is it just when you scroll down to the limit of the content and keep going?

Comment: Tricky to explain. I will try to record a video. 2 scenarios. 1: vertical scrolling - hold on input and drag vertically. Page should scroll but input should not fire.  2. Horizontal dragging off input - hold on input and drag off edge (no page scrolling). Now finger is on background of page - so also should not fire input.

Comment: Recorded a video showing the difference between the date picker firing after scrolling, vs a normal button which doesn't fire after scrolling: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UrMjXOH9imU This is Android 4.2.1 forge 1.4.33